# On the Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Linear Programming.

Tags: linear-programming

Having read the link:

[Why maximum/minimum of linear programming occurs at a vertex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896388/why-maximum-minimum-of-linear-programming-occurs-at-a-vertex)

I understand why the optimal solution of any linear programming problem must be on the corner or lies on a face of a convex polygon. But my question is about a proof given below:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_programming

I do not know why the next argument was

$$x^\ast - \frac{\epsilon}{2} \frac{c}{||c||} \in P$$

Sorry to ask this question, but I can't imagine where the term

$$\frac{\epsilon}{2} \frac{c}{||c||}$$

is coming from. Anyone, please enlighten me. Thanks.

Isn't it the contradiction will still be true even if we have, 
$$x^\ast - \frac{c}{||c||}$$.

The problem may be this construction may not be in $P$. Now, I really want to visualize the expressions 
$\frac{\epsilon}{2} \frac{c}{||c||} $ and $\frac{c}{||c||}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the proof, the assumption that $x^\ast$ is in the interior of $P$ is shown to lead to a contradiction.

Let

$$z = x^\ast - \frac{\epsilon}{2} \frac{c}{||c||}$$

Then

$$||z - x^\ast|| = \frac{\epsilon}{2} \frac{||c||}{||c||}= \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon,$$

and

$$z \in B_{\epsilon}(x^\ast) \subset P.$$

This was chosen to obtain a feasible point $z \in P$, such that $c^Tz < c^Tx^\ast$

Since $x^\ast$ is optimal we have a contradiction, implying that $x^\ast$ cannot lie in the interior of $P$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but can I clarify what is the difference between c and ||c|| ? is that the modulus? and $z$ must be in the interior of the ball centered at x* with radius $\epsilon$? ( I think I somehow get it)

Comment: @KenethAdrian: Yes, $||c||$ is the norm (magnitude) of the vector c.  With that choice we get a point in the ball where the objective function is smaller than the minimum at $x^{\ast}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, $\|c\|$ is the norm (or length) of the vector $c$. So $\frac{c}{\|c\|}$ as just a fancy way of saying "a unit vector in the direction of $c$".

Comment: so really instead of $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, they could chosen $\alpha \epsilon$ as long as $\alpha < 1$.

Comment: @Kiran K:  Yes you just need to get a contradiction by producing a point that is both in the interior of $P$ and such that $c^Tz < c^Tx^*$.

Comment: Hello! What is the function "B-epsilon"? Thanks!

Comment: @stats_noob: $B_\epsilon(x^*)$ is the open ball with center $x^*$ and radius $\epsilon$.   In general for $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$  we have $B_r(c) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\,:\, \|x-c\| < r\}$