# Maximal value, linear programming problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to find the maximal $\psi_1$ for the following linear programming problem:
\begin{align}
\max \frac{2}{3025}(525+121\psi_3 + 1089 \psi_4), \text{ s.t.}
\\
\end{align}
\begin{array}
 \text{0} \leq 1450 - 3267 \psi_3 - 5203 \psi_4 \\
\text{0} \leq \psi_3\\
\text{0} \leq \psi_4
\end{array}

Intuitively we want to make $\psi_3$ and $\psi_4$ as large as possible. 
My textbook states that:

> Since the constraints are linear, it follows that either all the
>   weight should be put on $\psi_3$ or $\psi_4$.

Why is that the case?

I have drawn the constraints, I see that the possible values should be inside a triangle. But why the optimal values should be one of the two corners of the triangle?

Comment: In a linear program, it's always the case that if there is an optimal solution (the LP isn't unbounded), then there is an optimal solution that lies at a corner of the feasible region.  There may be additional optimal solutions (with the same optimal objective value) along edges or higher dimensional faces of the feasible region.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Do you have a proof or some kind of intuition of why this is the case?

Comment: This is a standard theorem in linear programming that is usually proved in courses on that subject.  Chvatal's Linear Programming has a nice constructive proof based on the simplex method.

Comment: This topic (called the _fundamental theorem of linear programming_), is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896388/why-maximum-minimum-of-linear-programming-occurs-at-a-vertex) with some follow-up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002186/on-the-proof-of-fundamental-theorem-of-linear-programming).