# Coefficients($\sum 1$) of equation to get maximum output

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Lets say we have $4$ variables:
$$
x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4
$$
with coefficients: $a,b,c,d$ respectively,
and output $y$

With different combinations of $a,b,c,d$, we have a blackbox/unknown function, that returns the numeric output $(y)$.

Constraints here are:

$a + b + c + d = 1 $ and $ a,b,c,d \geq 0$

How can we find the coefficients $(a,b,c,d) $ for maximum $ y?$ Or, to get started, what assumptions could we start with.

Answer (score 1):

If the "unknown function" is really unknown, you cannot find the best output. You need some further assumptions about $f$ before you can start to calculate anything.

Comment: Thank you. But, to get started, if we assume it to be linear function, how can we proceed?

Comment: @skadoosh If it's a linear function, then it's of the form $\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c + \delta d$, and it's very very very easy to maximize this. You just have to evaluate the factors.

Comment: Could you point me to the right resources if possible, to achieve this? As I am not sure how to evaluate the factors, with the constraints given. Thank you.

Comment: @skadoosh $\alpha=f(1,0,0,0)$... no resource needed.

Comment: @skadoosh To expand further on what 5xum said, if you have $f(a,b,c,d)=x_0+ax_1+bx_2+cx_3+dx_4$ then the maximum must occur (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896388/why-maximum-minimum-of-linear-programming-occurs-at-a-vertex)) at one of the four points $(a,b,c,d)=(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, $(0,0,0,1)$, and you can just evaluate these to see which is greatest.

Answer (score 0):

If the function really is unknown (no linearity assumption), there are free user friendly softwares available to solve the problem, such as [NOMAD](https://www.gerad.ca/nomad/Project/Home.html).