# How to solve a number of math equations in Java to maximize profit?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a math problem with a bunch of equation like the ones below

```
x1 and x2 are variables
```

Constraints

```
x1 +  x2  <= z
ax1 + bx2 < p;
cx1 + dx2 < q;
```

I need to maximise profit, which looks like this in terms of equation

```
 maximize ex1+fx2
```

Does anybody how to solve these equations to maximise profit?

Comment: Draw a set of axes representing $(x_1,x_2)$, then sketch the constraint lines and shade the feasible region, the maximum of the objective function will occur at one of the corner points.

Comment: @Tavish Could you please explain why that would be the case?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896388/why-maximum-minimum-of-linear-programming-occurs-at-a-vertex